# How to fix 'UnicodeEncodeError' in python3 sendmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, sendmail

I want to send email with python.
But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 26, in <module>
    to_mail()
  File "mail.py", line 22, in to_mail
    smtp.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
  File "/home/centos/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 861, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.mail(from_addr, esmtp_opts)
  File "/home/centos/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 534, in mail
    self.putcmd("mail", "FROM:%s%s" % (quoteaddr(sender), optionlist))
  File "/home/centos/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 367, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/home/centos/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 352, in send
    s = s.encode(self.command_encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\uff20' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the environment I use.

- centos7
- Python 3.7.1
- `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` -> UTF8

My code is this.

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import charset


from_address = 'from＠xxxxx.jp'
to_address = 'haruraruru@xxxx.jp'

subject = "ERROR"
text = "check error.log"

msg = MIMEText(text,'Plane')
msg['Subject'] = Header(subject)
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address

def to_mail():
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtp.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()

to_mail()
```

What should I do to send me an email from python ?

Comment: your  `＠` in from_address seems different. Try chaning that

Comment: @Duck_dragon It's solved thanks to your advice. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your `@` symbol in the `from_address` variable is a non-standard  character. 
Potentially you copy and pasted it?

Try changing it to the standard `@` and see if it can be encoded